# Convert long into hexadecimal string (like a memory address)

Tags: c#, memory, long-integer

So I have these longs, 5488461193L and 5545007984L and I need to be able to convert them into memory addresses like this, 0x143EE69B0. I know they are memory addresses because they were originally memory addresses but I've only got the long versions of them. Sorry if its a bit hard to understand.

Comment: I've tried that but it diddnt work, I did manage to get it to work but I have to open a java project and do Long.ToHexString(5488461193L);

Comment: You should've asked **convert decimal long to hexadecimal string**

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Sorry, the language is C#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) with the x as formatting:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:X}", 5488461193L));
```

You can look up the syntax of the format string here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx